# MPAndroidChart plotting incorrect linear graph

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, mpandroidchart

Trying to implement mpandroidchart, but the graph is ending up useless because it is plotting the chart incorrectly.

Below is the snippet of how i try to implement.

```
 fun setGraph(cdata : ArrayList<Entry>){
            val lineChart: LineChart = bind.lineChartViewPage
            lineChart.setExtraOffsets(0f, 40f, 0f, 40f)
            lineChart.setDrawBorders(false)
            lineChart.setDrawGridBackground(false)
            lineChart.legend.isEnabled = false
            lineChart.description.isEnabled = false
            lineChart.setTouchEnabled(false)
            lineChart.isDragEnabled = false
            lineChart.setScaleEnabled(false)
            lineChart.setPinchZoom(false)
            lineChart.isAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled = false

            val lds = LineDataSet(cdata, "my data")
            lds.mode = LineDataSet.Mode.LINEAR
            lds.setDrawCircleHole(false)
            lds.setDrawCircles(false)
            lds.color = Color.parseColor("#ffffff")
            lds.lineWidth = 1.5f
            lds.isHighlightEnabled = false

            val lineDataSets: ArrayList<ILineDataSet> = ArrayList<ILineDataSet>()
            lineDataSets.add(lds)
            lds.setDrawValues(false)
            val lineData = LineData(lineDataSets)

            val ll1 = LimitLine(2.5F)
            ll1.lineWidth = 2f
            ll1.lineColor = Color.parseColor("#99ce7aff")

            val yAxisRight: YAxis = lineChart.axisRight
            yAxisRight.textColor = Color.WHITE
            yAxisRight.setDrawZeroLine(false)
            yAxisRight.setDrawAxisLine(false)
            yAxisRight.setCenterAxisLabels(true)
            yAxisRight.setDrawTopYLabelEntry(true)
            yAxisRight.setDrawGridLines(false)
            yAxisRight.setGranularity(1.0f)
            yAxisRight.isGranularityEnabled = true
            yAxisRight.setLabelCount(6, true)
            yAxisRight.removeAllLimitLines()
            yAxisRight.addLimitLine(ll1)
            yAxisRight.axisMaximum = 3.0f
            yAxisRight.axisMinimum = 0.0f

            val xAxis: XAxis = lineChart.xAxis
            xAxis.isEnabled = false
            xAxis.valueFormatter = null
            xAxis.setDrawLabels(false)
            xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)

            val yAxisLeft: YAxis = lineChart.axisLeft
            yAxisLeft.isEnabled = false
            yAxisLeft.setDrawLabels(false)
            yAxisLeft.setDrawGridLines(false)

            // hide legend
            val legend: Legend = lineChart.legend
            legend.isEnabled = false

            lineChart.data = lineData
            lineChart.data.notifyDataChanged()
            lineChart.notifyDataSetChanged()
            lineChart.invalidate()
        }
```

I tried out some combinations and found a different behavior if i comment out below lines :

```
yAxisRight.axisMaximum = 3.0f
yAxisRight.axisMinimum = 0.0f
```

Before commenting lines (incorrect plotting with limit line)

[image]

After commenting lines (correct plotting and limit line vanished)

[image]

Below is the dataset on which the graph is being plotted. here the max value is 0.8f and min value is 0.1f.

```
private fun fakeData():ArrayList<Entry>{
        val al: ArrayList<Entry> = ArrayList()
        al.add(Entry(1F, 0.2F))
        al.add(Entry(2F, 0.4F))
        al.add(Entry(3F, 0.5F))
        al.add(Entry(4F, 0.6F))
        al.add(Entry(5F, 0.3F))
        al.add(Entry(6F, 0.4F))
        al.add(Entry(7F, 0.6F))
        al.add(Entry(8F, 0.7F))
        al.add(Entry(9F, 0.4F))
        al.add(Entry(10F, 0.1F))
        al.add(Entry(11F, 0.3F))
        al.add(Entry(12F, 0.3F))
        al.add(Entry(13F, 0.5F))
        al.add(Entry(14F, 0.6F))
        al.add(Entry(15F, 0.47F))
        al.add(Entry(16F, 0.55F))
        al.add(Entry(17F, 0.66F))
        al.add(Entry(18F, 0.45F))
        al.add(Entry(19F, 0.46F))
        al.add(Entry(20F, 0.33F))
        al.add(Entry(21F, 0.4F))
        al.add(Entry(22F, 0.36F))
        al.add(Entry(23F, 0.37F))
        al.add(Entry(24F, 0.46F))
        al.add(Entry(25F, 0.74F))
        al.add(Entry(26F, 0.76F))
        al.add(Entry(27F, 0.79F))
        al.add(Entry(28F, 0.8F))
       
        return al
    }
```

If i dont set min and max values as below; then the limit line won't show up.

```
yAxisRight.axisMaximum = 3.0f
yAxisRight.axisMinimum = 0.0f
```

chart version : com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0

Please let me know if there is something wrong with this implementation or possible ways to correct this.

UPDATE :

Tried multiple dataset and found that defining custom yaxis min and max value is causing the chart to be drawn incorrectly. I cant understand why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033392/mpandroidchart-linechart-is-not-plotting-correctly

Comment: @UsamaAltaf already tried one of comment mentioned by philip in the question from link, accepted answer is not for me as i think the OP there is reading from some bluetooth device which is not my case and second answer crashes my code.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue and the fix is pretty easy, but not straightforward, though, you should set the same max and min values for both y-axises:

```
axisLeft.apply {
            axisMinimum = 0.0f
            axisMaximum = 3.0f
        }

axisRight.apply {
            axisMinimum = 0.0f
            axisMaximum = 3.0f
        }
```